# How can I pass dynamic content to the layout file(partials) in express handlebars?

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, templating-engine

In my NodeJS-express app, I'm using handlebars engine for templating. Routing with dynamic data is possible. I have one single layout file for my application. How can I pass data to template file dynamically?

Edits:

Here's my Template file.

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
      <div>
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a>Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a>about</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a>contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    {{{body}}}
  </body>
</html>
```

I need the nav Items(home, about, contact) are all from API call. not hardcoded.

Comment: Can you provide some code and point out your issue in code?

Comment: I've updated my question. Please do take a look. Thanks for finding time on this

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do this in your handlebars:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
      {{{navStuff}}}
    </nav>
    {{{body}}}
  </body>
</html>
```

And in your Express route, you can do this: (I assume its simple routing. You can adapt for ReactRouter V4)

```
app.get('/home', function(req, res, next){
return res.render('app',{
    body: toRender,
    navStuff: menu
    })
});
```

Similarly, if you have to make a databse call to fetch menu items based on page then you can adopt to this:

```
app.get('/home', function(req, res, next){
 getMenuFromDb(pathName).then(function(menu){
    return res.render('app',{
        body: toRender,
        navStuff: menu
        })
    });
})
```

})